# C# writing to property but no value is being returned

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, inheritance, properties

Making a windows forms board game where user can pick difficulty. This code will check that user has selected a difficulty and will then write this difficulty to the property.

```
if (combo_difficulty.SelectedIndex > -1) 
{
    Hide();
    //Main Menu form closes where user selects difficulty
    new Game().Show();
    //Game form where user player actual game

    Form2.playerStudent.Difficulty = combo_difficulty.Text;


    //This is a test and it outputs the difficulty as ecpected
    MessageBox.Show(Form2.playerStudent.Difficulty);
}
```

This is the student class showing the property that I'm referring to.

```
public class Student : Player
{
    private int _score;
    private string _difficulty;

    public Student(string username, string password, int score) : base(username, password) 
    {
        _score = Score;
    }

    public string Difficulty
    {
        get { return _difficulty; }
        set { _difficulty = value; }
    }
```

But when I want to read the selected difficulty in the game form no value is returned. I want this message to show to difficulty that user user selected in previous form.

```
public Game()
{
    InitializeComponent();          
    MessageBox.Show(Form2.playerStudent.Difficulty);
    //this message box is empty
    //other code...
}
```

Comment: What is Form2? It seems to be the class name Form2 not an instance of a Form2 class

Comment: Please delete the question then. Or edit it with high quality [mcve] and possibly provide an answer. (I recommend deletion as asking question you already know the answer for is very hard)

Comment: I would suggest place a breakpoint  in "get{ return _difficulty;}" if it is null then you would know it has not been set